# How to add an unsubscription link for email using Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I don't know how can I add unsubscription option to receive emails for users in Django? I need to add this option in case any user don't want to receive email from me.

Models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

username = models.CharField(
    _('username'),
    max_length=150,
    unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
    validators=[username_validator],
    error_messages={
        'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
    },
)
first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
```

Views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def email_users_date(request):
 if not request.method == 'POST':
    return

json_data = json.loads(json.loads(request.body)[0])
date=json_data.get('date')
print(json_data)
# date = request.POST.get('date')
for user in User.objects.all():
    subject = 'Data updated'

    template = get_template('interface/emaildata.html')
    context = {'user': user, 'date':date}

    text_msg = strip_tags(msg)
    send_mail(subject, text_msg, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [user.email], html_message=msg)

return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: you should to add field to your user model, for example boolean  `is_subcribed` with default `True` and after it create an api to set the field to `False`, after it generate url and add it to the email context.

Comment: glad if my comment helped you